# How exactly do Hair Tonics work on RDR2?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I've been playing Red Dead Redemption 2 for a while now. If I would guess, I'm halfway through **Chapter 3**.

My beard and hair are both on size 7.
For hair, this is the longest size the game provides, now for facial hair, I still have sizes 8, 9 and 10 to go for.

When I reached level 6, a prompt was shown stating that from now on my beard would only grow if I start to drink Hair Tonics.

I've been drinking Hair Tonics from the moment I got access to them on the beginning of **Chapter 2**, but to be honest, after dozens of hours I'm not sure how they work as the in-game description is poorly detailed.

I noticed that I can drink more than one Hair Tonic per day, but I can't tell if this really makes a difference. A quick search on Google says that this effect stacks as you sip more Hair Tonics, but I'm looking for confirmation as I couldn't confirm for myself from playing (I didn't pay too much attention to this game mechanic).

I have questions like:

- How long does the effect of a single Hair Tonic last?
- If more than one is taken, does the effect last longer or is just the growth rate that speeds up?
- How much is the rate growth increased for each Hair Tonic that I drink?
- Does the Hair Tonic effect rely solely on screen transitions (like sleeping, missions that advance the time to the moment they should begin, chapter transition and so on) or does it work when the player is free roaming and the time is passing by? Does it work on both situation then?

I think these questions cover most of the details involving Hair Tonics on this game.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find the Hair Growth section from the guide below:

[image]

Sorry for the poor quality. 
Taken from the official strategy guide for Red Dead Redemption 2 (available on the RDR2 app)

Comment: Just to see if I got the "how long the effect lasts" right... After I sip one Hair Tonic, that Hair Tonic will have its effect from the current stage to two stages after. So, if I drink one Hair Tonic while my beard is at level 2, the Tonic effect will last until stage 4. When I reach level 4, I'd need to drink another Hair Tonic which in turn will last until level 6. Is that right? Also, do you know if loading a saved game counts as "respawning"?